# How to get a Constant Name using Expressions and/or reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constants

How to get a Constant Name using Expressions and/or reflection?

I've written the below but "me" is always null?

```
 public static class Test1
    {
        public const string CampaignManager = "This_CAMPAIGN_MANAGER";
    }

 public static class ReflectionHelper
    {
        // <summary>
        // Get the name of a static or instance property from a property access lambda.
        // </summary>
        // <typeparam name="T">Type of the property</typeparam>
        // <param name="propertyLambda">lambda expression of the form: '() => Class.Property' or '() => object.Property'</param>
        // <returns>The name of the property</returns>
        public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyLambda)
        {
            var me = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;

            if (me == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("You must pass a lambda of the form: '() => Class.Property' or '() => object.Property'");
            }

            return me.Member.Name;
        }
    }

var campaignManager = ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyName(() => Test1.CampaignManager);
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128350/No-More-Magic-Strings-Presenting-string-of) maybe can help.

Comment: This is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304756/apply-memberexpression-to-an-object-to-retrieve-property-value   You passing the value of the property not the property itself

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a const field with your Reflection helper since the Body of the lambda expression is a `ConstantExpression` and not a `MemberExpression`.
Replace

```
 public const string CampaignManager = "This_CAMPAIGN_MANAGER";
```

with

```
 public static string CampaignManager = "This_CAMPAIGN_MANAGER";
```

Comment: but constant should be constant)

Comment: @SalientBrain Ups, my bad. Then, I don't think its possible.

Comment: however resources are static, but used often

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't get constant name because

```
ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyName(() => Test1.CampaignManager);
```

turning into

```
ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyName(() => "This_CAMPAIGN_MANAGER");
```

by compiler