# Apply MemberExpression to an object to retrieve Property value

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a generic function that takes a MemberExpression and an object and returns the value of the Property defined in the member expression.

Here's an example of the code to get the Property name.

```
public static TProperty GetPropertyName<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, TModel model)
{
    if (expression.Body is MemberExpression)
    {
        return ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        var op = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand;
        return ((MemberExpression)op).Member.Name;
    }
}
```

But I want to retrieve the value of the property from the model:

```
public static string GetPropertyValue<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, TModel model)
{
    if (expression.Body is MemberExpression)
    {
        // how do I apply the expression.Body to get the value of the property from model??

    }
    else
    {
        var op = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand;
        return ((MemberExpression)op).Member.Name;
    }
}
```

The way I call this function is:

```
GetPropertyValue<ObjectModel,bool>(m => m.somebool, m);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MemberExpression` refers to [`MemberInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.member%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will be `PropertyInfo` in case of property expression:

```
static class MemberExpressionHelper
{
    public static TProperty GetPropertyValue<TModel, TProperty>(TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        // case with `UnaryExpression` is omitted for simplicity
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;

        var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
        return (TProperty)propertyInfo.GetValue(model);
    }
}
```

Besides, it is more natural to swap parameters (first is `model`, second is expression). As a side effect, this allows compiler to infer type arguments:

```
var bar = MemberExpressionHelper.GetPropertyValue(foo, _ => _.Bar);
```

Comment: How do you do this for nested members ?